# Throttling method cURL

Tags: php, curl, throttling

I'm working on a project using an api, my subscription allows me 2 requests per second.

This API allows you to find words that are related to another word.

My project is to use this API recursively.
the word A gives the word B and C
words B and C each give 2 words, etc., recursively, on a limit that the user specifies.

I store each word in a "word" object. In the __construct of this object, I call the function which calls this API, and which transforms each result into a new object.

Everything works, the only concern is that when the specified recursivity layer is too high, the API doesn't return anything, even though I have a timer of 0.5 seconds.

So I set up a loop. As long as the response to my cURL request is not a 200, I replay it, with a timer of 0.5 seconds.

```
        $a = 200;
        $httpcode = 0;
        while ($httpcode !== $a) {

            $postRequest = [
                'content' => $this->getMot(),
                'lang' => 'fr',
                'limit' => $this->getLimite(),
                'key' => "//////////////////////"
            ];
            $cURLConnection = curl_init('https://api.keywords.gg/entities');
            curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
                ['Content-Type: application/json']);
            curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($postRequest));
            curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $apiResponse = curl_exec($cURLConnection);
            $httpcode = curl_getinfo($cURLConnection, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            $apiResponse = curl_exec($cURLConnection);
            curl_close($cURLConnection);
        }
```

I think my throttling method is wrong. Could you give me some advice?

Comment: Post your actual code here, not a picture of your code.

Comment: Images of code is bad for accessibility, bad for searching and make it impossible to copy your code to run it to find any errors.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [sleep documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep) it expects an integer.

You send a floating number 0.6 then cast to the integer value 0.

So your sleep call become:

```
sleep(0)
```

You need to use [usleep(int microseconds)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php) if you need more precision.

```
usleep(600)
```